# I am attempting to create an interactive map in tkinter using mpl_toolkits Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, matplotlib-basemap

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTk, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

# Create the window
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")

# Get the canvas to draw on
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=800)

# Create a figure
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


# Create a map
m = Basemap(projection='mill')
m.drawcoastlines(color="white")
m.drawcountries(color="white")
m.fillcontinents(color="grey", lake_color="black")
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color="black")

# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTk(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
button = tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit', command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

tk.mainloop()
# Create a dictionary of countries and their corresponding buttons
countries_buttons = {}

# Iterate through each country and create a corresponding button
for country in m.drawcountries():
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=country, command=(lambda country=country: print(country)))
    countries_buttons[country] = btn
    canvas.create_window(m(m.countries_info[country]['xcenter'], 
                            m.countries_info[country]['ycenter']),
                        window=btn)

# Show the map
plt.show()

root.mainloop()
```

I get no errors on the code when I comment out the iteration for country in m.drawcountries() part,

I actually get a plot of the Basemap in my Spyder IDE Plots interface. However the map doesnt plot on my tkinter window. I am attempting to create a button off of every country.

I would really appreciate some help. Best!!

Comment: It's unclear. See [ask]. What is your problem? You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details. A brief look shows full of errors - multiple calls of ```mainloop()```, not using ```FigureCanvasTkAgg```, an unused ```tkinter.Canvas```, incorrectly embedding a ```NavigationToolbar2Tk```, incorrectly enumerating on a ```LineCollection```, wrongly calling ```create_window()``` on a ```FigureCanvasTk```, using the imaginary property ```countries_info``` of a ```Basemap```, etc.

Comment: Also use the ```plt.figure()``` instead of the ```Figure()```.